# Android NDK GLThread

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, kotlin

I'm trying to create a simple animation in android using the NDK and unfortunately my code is throwing an `Exception`.

`A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 16198 (GLThread 739)`

I didn't know what's the meaning of this error.

These are some of my code.

**`Coin.cpp`**

```
void Coin::Render(GLuint textureId, GLuint positionHandle, GLuint texCoord, GLint matrixHandle, GLint samplerLoc) {
    // Bind the texture to this unit
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

    // Enable generic vertex attribute array
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoord);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, mVertices);
    // Prepare the texture coordinates
    glVertexAttribPointer(texCoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, mUVCoord);
    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, 0);
    //  Set the sampler texture unit to 0, where we have saved the texture
    glUniform1i(samplerLoc, 0);

    // Draw the triangle
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndices);

    // Disable vertex array
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(texCoord);
}
```

This is how I declare my array `Coin` object, and I am thinking it seems like `ArrayList<Coin>` in Java.

**`CoinRenderer.h`**

```
vector<Coin> mCoinCollection;
```

This is the part where the error is throwing, The code is working without the `coin.Render()` or `coin.translate()` but if I uncomment this code the code is not working.

**`CoinRenderer.cpp`**

```
void CoinRenderer::drawCoin() {
    // glUseProgram(programHandle);
    glUseProgram(imageHandle);

    long slowTime = GLUtils::currentTimeMillis() % 100000L;
    int elapse = (int) ((0.01f) * (slowTime));

    for (int i = 0; i < mCoinCollection.size(); i++) {
        Coin coin = mCoinCollection[i];
        if (mCurrentTime < elapse) {
            //int nextCoinFace = coin.getNextCoinFace();
            //coin.setTextureId(textures[i]);
            // This is also the line where the error is throwing.
            //coin.translate(0.0f, 0.20f);
        }
        // This line where the error is throwing.
        coin.Render(coin.getTextureId(), mPositionHandle, mTexCoord, mMatrixHandle, mSamplerLoc);
    }

    if (!hasVisibleCoin()) {
        LOGD("All coins y < 0");
        glDeleteProgram(imageHandle);
    }

    mCurrentTime = elapse;
}
```

Here are some of the additional code if its needed.

**`CoinRenderer.kt`**

```
class CoinRenderer(private val context: Context) : GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    override fun onDrawFrame(gl: GL10?) {
        nativeDrawFrame()
    }

    override fun onSurfaceChanged(gl: GL10?, width: Int, height: Int) {
        nativeSurfaceChange(width, height)
    }

    override fun onSurfaceCreated(gl: GL10?, config: EGLConfig?) {
        val assetManager = context.assets
        nativeSurfaceCreate(assetManager)
    }

    external fun nativeSurfaceCreate(assetManager: AssetManager)
    external fun nativeSurfaceChange(width: Int, height: Int)
    external fun nativeDrawFrame()
    external fun drawNewCoin(coinSize: Int)
    external fun nativeClearSurface(isClearSurface: Boolean)

    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("coin-lib")
        }
    }
}
```

**`CoinGL.kt`**

```
class CoinGL(context: Context) : GLSurfaceView(context) {

    private var mRenderer : CoinRenderer? = null

    init {
        // Set openGL version
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2)

        setZOrderOnTop(true)
        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0)
        holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888)

        mRenderer = CoinRenderer(context)
        setRenderer(mRenderer)

        renderMode = RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY
    }

    fun drawNewCoin(coinSize: Int) {
        queueEvent ({
            mRenderer?.drawNewCoin(coinSize)
            mRenderer?.nativeClearSurface(false)
        })
    }
}
```

**PS: I am just a newbee in Android OPENGL NDK or in C++, if you found or saw some very wrong declaration or use kindly please explain it to me. Thank you.**

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change
`vector<Coin> mCoinCollection;`
to
`vector<Coin*> mCoinCollection;`